# PowerPoint 2010 looped presentation will not advance

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I have 2 powerpoint presentations.

The first is set to loop until a hidden button is pressed, which calls up the second presentation.
 To do this, I inserted an Action Button Shape with a hyperlink to the second presentation.

On click, the second presentation comes up as desired.  However, the second presentation is set to advance on mouse click.  But when it's called up, it will not advance.

I've done this before, but this time, I am stumped why the second presentation will not advance by mouse click.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you open the 2nd presentation directly in PP, does the click to advance work as expected?

Comment: Yes it does.  If I open the 2nd presentation by itself, it advances on click.  I cannot figure out why the hyperlink is making the presentation stick on the first slide